how to send/get values from mainform label to Childform1 label and Childform2 label with VB.NET
I'm Trying to send/get values from mainform label to Childform1 label and Childform2 label with VB.NET
If you see the gif (gif result code) in mainform then there appears ADMIN (LblUsername) and A (LblLocation) so I want to appear in OPENFORM1 & OPENFORM2
Please Guide Me
Code in LoginForm
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class LoginForm
    Inherits BaseFixedForm
    Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()
    End Sub
    Private Sub Login()
        Dim userModel = New UserModel().Login(txtUsername.Text, txtPassword.Text)

        If userModel IsNot Nothing Then
            Dim mainForm As Form
            mainForm = New MainForm(userModel)
            Me.Hide()
            AddHandler mainForm.FormClosed, AddressOf MainForm_SessionClosed
            mainForm.Show()
        Else
            ShowMessage("Incorrect username or password")
        End If
    End Sub
    Private Sub ShowMessage(message As String)
        lblErrorMessage.Text = "    " & message
        lblErrorMessage.Visible = True
    End Sub
    Private Sub btnLogin_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnLogin.Click
        Login()
    End Sub
    Private Sub MainForm_SessionClosed(sender As Object, e As FormClosedEventArgs)
        Logout()
    End Sub
    Private Sub Logout()

        Me.Show()
        lblErrorMessage.Visible = False
        txtPassword.Clear()
        txtUsername.Clear()
        txtUsername.Focus()
    End Sub

End Class
Public Class UserDao
    Private ReadOnly connectionString As String
    Public Sub New()
        connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\test07092024.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;"
    End Sub

    Protected Function GetConnection() As OleDbConnection

        Return New OleDbConnection(connectionString)
    End Function

    Public Function Login(ByVal username As String, ByVal password As String) As User
        'Validate the username and password for login.

        Using connection = GetConnection() 'Obtener la conexion.
            connection.Open() 'Open the connection.
            Using command = New OleDbCommand()
                command.Connection = connection
                command.CommandText = "select *from Users where (userName=@username and password=@pass)"
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", username)
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", password)
                command.CommandType = CommandType.Text
                Dim reader As OleDbDataReader = command.ExecuteReader()
                If reader.Read() Then
                    Dim userObj = New User With {
                        .Id = CInt(reader(0)),
                        .Username = reader(1).ToString(),
                        .Location = reader(3).ToString()
                    }
                    Return userObj
                Else
                    Return Nothing
                End If
            End Using
        End Using
    End Function

End Class
Public Class UserModel
    Private _id As Integer
    Private _username As String
    Private _password As String
    Private _Location As String
    Private _userDao As UserDao
    Public Sub New()
        _userDao = New UserDao()
    End Sub

    Public Property Id As Integer
        Get
            Return _id
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            _id = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Property Username As String
        Get
            Return _username
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _username = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Property Password As String
        Get
            Return _password
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _password = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Property Location As String
        Get
            Return _Location
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _Location = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Function Login(ByVal username As String, ByVal password As String) As UserModel
        'Login.
        Dim result = _userDao.Login(username, password)

        If result IsNot Nothing Then
            Return MapUserModel(result)
        Else
            Return Nothing
        End If
    End Function
    'Mapping entity model to domain model.
    Private Function MapUserModel(ByVal userEntity As User) As UserModel
        'Map a single object.
        Dim userModel = New UserModel() With {
            .Id = userEntity.Id,
            .Username = userEntity.Username,
            .Password = userEntity.Password,
            .Location = userEntity.Location
        }
        Return userModel
    End Function
End Class
Public Class User
    Public Property Id As Integer
    Public Property Username As String
    Public Property Password As String
    Public Property Location As String

End Class


Code in MainForm
Public Class MainForm
    Inherits BaseMainForm
    Private listChildForms As List(Of Form)
    Private activeChildForm As Form 'Obtains or sets the currently displayed child form.

    Public Sub New(connectedUser As UserModel)
        'Use this constructor at login and submit a user view model
        InitializeComponent()
        'Me.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None
        listChildForms = New List(Of Form)()
        LoadUserData(connectedUser)
    End Sub
    Public Sub LoadUserData(connectedUser As UserModel)
        'Upload the logged-in user's data in the side menu.
        LblUsername.Text = connectedUser.Username
        LblLocation.Text = connectedUser.Location
    End Sub
    Private Sub OpenChildForm(Of ChildForm As {Form, New})(ByVal senderMenuButton As Object)

        Dim menuButton As Button = CType(senderMenuButton, Button) ' Where the form opens, you can submit a null value, if you're not trying to open a form from a different control than the side menu buttons.
        Dim form As Form = listChildForms.OfType(Of ChildForm)().FirstOrDefault() 'Find if the form is already instantiated or has been previously displayed.

        If activeChildForm IsNot Nothing AndAlso form Is activeChildForm Then Return 'If the form is the same as the current active form, return and do nothing.

        If form Is Nothing Then 'If the form doesn't exist, then create the instance and display it in the desktop panel.
            form = New ChildForm() 'Instantiation form.  
            form.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None 'Remove the Edge.
            form.TopLevel = False 'Indicate that the form is not top-level 
            form.Dock = DockStyle.Fill 'Set the Dock Style to Full (Fill the Desktop Panel)          
            listChildForms.Add(form) 'Add Child Form to Form List.

            If menuButton IsNot Nothing Then 'If the menu button is different from null:
                ActivateButton(menuButton) 'Activate/Highlight the button.
                AddHandler form.FormClosed, Sub(s, e) DeactivateButton(menuButton) 'When the form closes, disable the button.
            End If

            btnChildFormClose.Visible = True 'Show the Close Secondary Form Button.
        End If
        CleanDesktop() 'Delete the current child form from the desktop panel
        panelDesktop.Controls.Add(form) 'Add Secondary Form to the Desktop Dashboard
        panelDesktop.Tag = form ' Store the form
        form.Show() 'Show the form
        form.BringToFront() ' Bring to the front
        form.Focus() 'Focus the form
        'lblCaption.Text = form.Text 'Set the title of the form.
        activeChildForm = form 'Set as active form.
    End Sub
    Private Sub ActivateButton(menuButton As Button)
        menuButton.ForeColor = Color.RoyalBlue
        'menuButton.BackColor = panelMenuHeader.BackColor;
    End Sub
    Private Sub DeactivateButton(menuButton As Button)
        menuButton.ForeColor = Color.SlateGray
        'menuButton.BackColor = panelSideMenu.BackColor;
    End Sub
    Private Sub CleanDesktop()
        If activeChildForm IsNot Nothing Then
            activeChildForm.Hide()
            panelDesktop.Controls.Remove(activeChildForm)
        End If
    End Sub
#Region "- Open Secondary Forms"
    Private Sub btnOPENFORM1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnOPENFORM1.Click
        OpenChildForm(Of OPENFORM1)(sender)
    End Sub
    Private Sub btnOPENFORM2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnOPENFORM2.Click
        OpenChildForm(Of OPENFORM2)(sender)
    End Sub
#End Region
End Class

Result code in file gif.

Desired result
OPENFORM1

ADMIN

A


OPENFORM2

ADMIN

A


Update code
So in the OPENFORM1 form and OPENFORM2 Have each label, namely : LblUsername & LblLocation
code in OPENFORM1
Public Class OPENFORM1
    Private Sub OPENFORM1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        MainForm.LblUsername.Text = LblUsername.Text
        MainForm.LblLocation.Text = LblLocation.Text
    End Sub

End Class



code in OPENFORM2
Public Class OPENFORM2
    Private Sub OPENFORM2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        MainForm.LblUsername.Text = LblUsername.Text
        MainForm.LblLocation.Text = LblLocation.Text
    End Sub
End Class




but I have an error Reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference

You could pass your usermodel to your child form in OpenChildForm.

@AndrewMortimer , Thank you for your response, please guide me. You mean this in  event button OpenChildForm(Of OPENFORM1)(sender)

Yes in the event button should work.

@AndrewMortimer , you mean after this line OpenChildForm(Of OPENFORM1)(sender) then OPENFORM1.LblUsername = LblUsername OPENFORM1.LblLocation = LblLocation I tried it didn't appear in form OPENFORM1 please guide me

Add this method into the child form and call it: LoadUserData

@AndrewMortimer , you mean after this line OpenChildForm(Of OPENFORM1)(sender) then LoadUserData(connectedUser) but I have an error 'connectedUser' is not declared . Please Guide me

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
